# Parcoordplot with density behaviour

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I am using GGally R package to draw a parcoordplot, but I noticed that if you have two equal rows, one with label 0 and the other with label 1, the color of the line will be the color of the last row.
For instance if you have the following dataset:

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3]       
   [1,]    1    1    1
   [2,]    1    1    1
   [3,]    1    1    0
```

And you if call ggparcoord(dataset, columns = 1:2, groupColumn = 'V3',scale = 'globalminmax') the color that you will see is the color for label 0.

However, I do not want the last color but the most predominant one. In this case since I have three equal rows, two with label 1 and other with label 0, I want to show the color for label 1 independently of the row order. How can I do this?